# Selenium: Extract NBA Data to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, selenium

I want to be able to extract this data cleanly into an excel file but not quite sure how to parse the text. So far, I am able to store the table into an element and print everything.

Here is my code below:

```
# Import libraries.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

# Create a Chrome Session
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\Gene\\Desktop\\chromedriver')
driver.get('https://stats.nba.com/team/1610612739/onoffcourt-traditional/?Season=2017-18&SeasonType=Regular%20Season&PerMode=Totals')

# Enter Date
d = '10/17/2017'

# Click Advanced Tab
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[5]").click()

# Send Date
date1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/input")

date1.send_keys(d)

date2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div/input")

date2.send_keys(d)

# Find Table
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/stats-run-it/a").click()

# Store Table
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/nba-stat-table[2]/div[2]/div[1]')

# View Table
print(table.text)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What I can think of is you can first split your text by newline:

```
rows=table.text.split('\n')
```

Now you have one string for every row of your future DataFrame/Excel. Then, you can split every element of `rows`, to get every individual observation:

```
element=[]
for r in rows:
    element.append([i for i in r.split(' ')])
```

Lastly, you can turn this list of lists into a DataFrame:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(element)
```

To turn the first row into your column names and then dropping it:

```
df.columns=df.iloc[0]
df=df.reindex(df.index.drop(0))
```

Now you have something quite similar to what you want. Then you can export it:

```
df.to_excel('nba.xlsx')
```

That's the best you can *easily* do with your text formatting. If you want something prettier, you'll have to work out a better solution, but probably using list slicing you can make it .